# C# compiler error: Assets\Scripts\CamraMotor.cs(13,41): error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial for a 2D game in unity, but I keep getting a compiling error telling me that a new expression requires (), [], or a {}, but when I look at my code I cant find where I went wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamraMotor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform lookAt;
    public float boundX = 0.15f;
    public float boundY = 0.05f;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 delta = new Vector3.zero;

        // This is to see if we're on the inside the bounds om the X asxis
        float deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
        if(deltaX > boundX || deltaX < -boundX)
        {
            if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
            {
                delta.x = deltaX - boundX;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.x = deltaX + boundX;
            }
        }

        // This is to see if we're inside the bounds on the Y axis
        float deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
        if (deltaY > boundY || deltaY < -boundY)
        {
            if (transform.position.y < lookAt.position.y)
            {
                delta.y = deltaY - boundY;
            }
            else
            {
                delta.y = deltaY + boundY;
            }
        }

        transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, deltaY, 0);
    }
}
```

it said the error can be found (13,41)

I tried retyping the whole script but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Replace `Vector3 delta = new Vector3.zero;` with `Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the error:

`Vector3 delta = new Vector3.zero;`

The `new` keyword is used to create a new object, but that object needs a constructor.

Remove the `new` and it should work fine.

This is likely an error in your tutorial. It looks like `Zero` is a field and not a class, therefore it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Correct. `Vector3` is likely the `struct` described in [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html), and `zero` is not a nested type inside the struct, so this confirms your answer. _Addition:_ Whether `zero` is a static field or a static property with a `get` accessor, is less relevant.